# HttpRequestException using HttpClient at the activated event in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I noticed that when I press the Windows button while doing a network request, and then, press the back button to come back to the app, the process is killed (HttpRequestException is thrown). I know that this happens because the Operating Sytem closes all networking connections when the app goes to the dormant state.

How can I handle properly this scenario? I mean, if I catch the exception, I should retry the network operations. I read that I could use a bool property that is set in the activated event to retry operations, but I don't like this approach because is easy that it fails.

Answer (score 1):

This article from 2012 gives a good overview of what happens to a WebClient instance when the app is *suspended* or *tombstoned*, and some solutions...

http://community.appamundi.com/blogs/andywigley/archive/2012/04/08/what-happens-to-network-calls-when-your-wp7-app-goes-dormant.aspx

As `HttpClient` is a newer API, which supports Async/Await, another suggestion would be to use one of the *RetryOnFault* patterns from the [Consuming the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873173%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you. That is the page where I saw the solution of setting a global bool variable to true when the app goes dormant, but I don't like that approach because when should I put it to false? It's very easy that it fails. On the other hand, I like the RetryOnFault pattern and maybe with the combination with something like the first solution could work. I'll tell you if I can make this to be done.

Comment: I don't use the global FromTomstoned/FromDeactivated (or other) approach, I handle to exception and retry for a better experience - works the same for suspend/deactivate and general errors.

Comment: But how do you distinguish the error coming from the app being deactivated from when the request failed for timeout or other general request error? I think that all the general errors should be retried X times and then show an error message but the deactivated/reactivate errors should be always retried without message. Do you understand what I'm saying? Any ideas?

Comment: The exception should tell you, at least it does with `WebClient` - HttpClient is just an abstraction on `HttpWebRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

Register to

```
 PhoneApplicationService.Current.Closing
```

It will be fired when your app is closing. There you can handle stopping any processes you need to.

Comment: The problem here is not to stop nothing. The OS stops the network requests when the app is deactivated and when I reactivate the app, it crashes because all that stopped network requests throw an HttpRequestException.

So, I am asking how can I detect when that calls were stopped and how can I retry them.

Comment: I understand what you are asking and I'm telling you that the way you handle this problem is by stopping the requests before they error out. Then, when your app is resumed you continue your requests.